# Loading date/time into Sencha Touch Model

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm using Sencha Touch 1.1.  I have the following model and store:

```
Ext.regModel(TrafficResponse.Models.IncidentReports, {
    idProperty: 'Id',
    fields: [
        {name: 'Id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'TMCRequestedTime', type: 'date'},
        {name: 'TRUDetectedTime', type: 'date'},
        {name: 'SiteArrivalTime', type: 'date'},
        {name: 'SiteDepartedTime', type: 'date'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id: TrafficResponse.Stores.IncidentReports
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json'
    }
});


truApp.stores.incidentReportStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: TrafficResponse.Models.IncidentReports,
    id: TrafficResponse.Stores.IncidentReports,
    autoLoad: true
});
```

I set the date value using a date/time picker (not a standard Sencha control) and use the `updateRecord` method of the form to update the model with the values on the form.

After `sync()` has been done the record in localstorage has the date value in the following format:

2012-02-09T22:15:00.000Z

The value on the date/time picker is Friday, February 10 2012 08:15 so it appears as though the GMT value is being stored.

After refreshing the browser and loading the model from localstorage, the value in localstorage is retained as above but it is not loaded into the model.  The value in the model is `null`.

If I change the model and add `dateFormat: 'c'` to the field configuration, the date is loaded into the model with the following value:

Thu Feb 09 2012 22:15:00 GMT+1000 (E. Australia Standard Time)

The date is displayed on the form with that value as well which is 10 hours before the date that was set originally.

What can I do to get the date to load correctly and retain the timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of stepping though code I discovered that the issue was caused by `date-js`.  I removed `date-js` and used Sencha Date functions and everything now works correctly.